# How to calculate sum list and tuple using RDD Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sum, tuples, rdd

I have a RDD that looks like this

```
val elements = List((8, 12), (9, 10), (5, 16))
```

output should look like this

```
result_1 = 22 #sum of the first element
result_2 = 38 #sum of the second element
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to calculate the sum.

```
val result1 = rdd.map(_._1).sum()
val result2 = rdd.map(_._2).sum()

val result = rdd.reduce((a, b) => (a._1 + b._1, a._2 + b._2))

// result1: Double = 22.0
// result2: Double = 38.0
// result: (Int, Int) = (22,38)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `fold` ;

```
rdd.fold(0,0)((first,second) =>(first._1 + second._1, first._2 + second._2)))
```

For explanation fold function;

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scala-reduce-fold-or-scan/